# Usage of "desired"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Quoted from manga *Berserk*, a demon said the following:

> In any event...my **desired** is just one thing...

I think it is not a typo for "desire", since I had seen it multiple times in the manga, but can desired be used as a noun? I only found it to be an adjective in dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a stretch, but it might be possible to use almost any adjective/participle as a noun sometimes, compare "*Dearly* ***beloved***,..." or "*Remember the* ***fallen***".  I have not seen "*desired*" used that way, though.

Comment: In the context of a demon speaking, "my desired" could possibly refer to "my desired victim" or something like that.

Comment: "My precious"...